# Is it better to always use `super()__init__()` for subclass inheritance. what advantage does it offer?

Tags: python, oop, super

All of the python I know, is entirely self taught, but my goal is to of course try to learn what is best practice/ common convention and try to understand why.

I've only recently dug more into OOP, so in efforts to practice OOP, I wrote a blackjack game as I've heard that's a decent quick project to learn a lot of OOP concepts.

The full program can be found here(GitHub): [my blackjack game](https://github.com/zsonnen/blackjack) if needed for context (vs just posting the entirety here)

but I'm struggling to understand exactly what `super()__init()` does, and if its preferable compared to how I used subclasses: for simplicity take just the following two: `Deck` and `MultiDeck` which is a subclass of `Deck`
The following is a snipet from the game:

```
import collections
import random
import time 

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['value', 'suit'])


class Deck:

    values = [str(v) for v in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = "Spades Diamonds Hearts Clubs".split()
    suit_symbols = ['♠','♦','♥','♣']

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in self.suits for value in self.values]

    def __repr__(self):
        deck_cards = "Deck()\n"
        for card in self.cards:
            deck_cards += f"({card.value}-{card.suit})"
        return deck_cards

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self.cards[position]

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def reset(self):
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in self.suits for value in self.values]

class MultiDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self, num_decks):
        Deck.__init__(self)
        self.values = Deck.values * num_decks

    # reshuffle when deck is < 50% length
    def is_shuffle_time(self, num_decks):
        return  len(self) < (len(MultiDeck(num_decks))/2)

    def shuffle_time(self):
        print("Reshuffling the Deck...\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Reshuffling the Deck...\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Reshuffling the Deck...\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.reset()
        self.shuffle()
```

Contrast that to Below: which would be the better way: for one, should super() be declared in the superclass `Deck` or left out? I've stumbled upon a lot of seemingly different answers (but its possible that might be a result of python 3 compared to older versions)
Is it better to instead define `MultiDeck` like:

```
class MultiDeck(Deck):

    def __init__(self, num_decks):
        super().__init__()
        self.values = super().values * num_decks
```

and on that last line, in initializing `self.values` is it better to use `Deck.values` or `super().values`

If using super() is in fact better practice, what advantage or added benefit does `super().__init()` provide. and is writing it like `Deck.__init__(self)` more frowned upon (if so, why?)
I hope I even used it correctly, for example purposes...from what I've read that seemed to be the way to use super(), but please correct me if not.
Thank you for any input in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Python super() with \_\_init\_\_() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: @FishingCode it does to a degree. thankyou. Though I may have to learn a bit more about MRO. Is it reasonable to say, that super() is very beneficial when a class has many subclasses (whereas my code having one subclass its less obvious what the advantage is), does it essentially allow for a far more fluid way to pass down inheritance? without the need to write the actual name of the class, but rather use super, I'd imagine that's advantageous - vs manually renaming all subclasses if the superclass was renamed: tho please correct me. are there additional benefits to the one's I thought up?

Comment: .. [Super considered super!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) - video

Comment: `super()` is more advantageous in the case where you have several classes that need to achieve multiple things, essentially you're gaining multiple inheritance with the use of `super()`. It's beneficial when re-writting what the "parent" class is doing thus it does the lookup from the help of the parent class. Your idea sounds about right, in that if you do not see a case where you don't see a `super()` then no need of it, where ever you can apply the DRY approach, is what one should be aiming for in terms of code quality.

Comment: this [example](https://appdividend.com/2019/01/22/python-super-function-example-super-method-tutorial/) does a great job, in terms of explaining `super()` without confusing the concept off it too much.

Comment: @FishingCode ty. was helpful. wasn't until multi-inheritance was mentioned that it became more obv as to the benefits (funny enough, the article you linked, didn't use super() in example for that), but I found [this example](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/super-multiple-inheritance-diamond-problem) . but I can certainly see how it can be useful-  and only needing one super() call - as order is built into its MRO? if I understood. but thanks again